# How to write custom ASP.NET MVC HTML Helper like Html.TextBoxFor and set correct name attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to have custom `Html.DateTimePickerFor(a => a.Fields[0].Id, value)`

so the result should be like this:

```
<div name="Fields[0].Id"></div>
```

Currently I use `Html.DatetimePicker("Fields[0].Id", value)` and it works perfectly, but I wan to generate dynamic name.

So the question is how to set correct `"name"` attribute?

Comment: At you attempting to create an `TextBoxFor` version for DateTime fields or an `EditFor` template for a specific field?  I think this is the most important factor at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It works for me.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DateTimePickerFor<TModel, TProp>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProp>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string name   = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        ... rest of code here
    }
```

The magic comes from `System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText()`. Once you have the name from your expression, you can apply it to your div.

[GetExpressionText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428401%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: Be careful with this method as it omits 2 things which `NameFor()` does: 1) attribute encoding and 2) name qualification. See the MVC source, where the name is further qualified by calling: `html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name)`

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @TimMedora - what version of mvc is that for? I see it in the current version of the source, but in the MVC3 app that I pulled my snippet from, I don't see that method. Is it MVC4 only? If you have an MVC4 app, then your solution sounds like the better way to go.

Comment: MVC3 RTM, `NameExtensions` class - After seeing your answer, I was curious how it differed from `NameFor()`. `NameFor()` calls `GetExpressionText()` and passes the result to an overload which returns `MvcHtmlString.Create(html.AttributeEncode(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name)));` The attribute encoding probably isn't a big deal, but the name qualification can cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (adapted from working code):

```
public static IHtmlString DateTimePickerFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,

    // other input parameters as needed

) {
    // metadata gives you access to a variety of useful things, such as the
    // display name and required status
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( expression, helper.ViewData );
    string markup = ""; // markup for your input            

    var name = helper.NameFor( expression ); // getting the name

    return MvcHtmlString.Create( markup  );
}
```